# What does it mean for correlation functions to be dominated by the vacuum block for a 2D CFT?

Tags: conformal-geometry, chern-simons-theory, gravity-theory

In a 2D CFT, correlation functions dominated by the vacuum block have no conical defects. You can calculate the OPE and determine the correlation function using the D-S equations and cancel out UV divergences with the Ward Id. However, with conical defects, you need to use a saddle point approximation in Gravitational theories like Chern-Simons. These are higher spin currents generated by conical defects.

My question is: What changes when you evaluate an OPE with correlation functions dominated by the conformal block and then evaluate conical defects using saddle point approximation action in gravity theories like Chern-Simons? And does evaluating Wilson lines for a zero cosmological constant agree with calculation done in the 2-D CFT?